# Is it okay to write i.e. at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is it aceptable to write "i.e." at the begining of a sencnce?

For example:

> Does the above formula equal 2?
>   i.e. does (insert simple formula here) equal 10?

or should it be

> Does the above formula equal 2?
>   I.e. does (insert simple formula here) equal 10?

or both capitalised?

> Does the above formula equal 2?
>   I.E. does (insert simple formula here) equal 10?

Or would it be better to write

> Does the above formula equal 2?
>   By that I mean does (insert simple formula here) equal 10?

or

> Does the above formula equal 2?
>   That is, does (insert simple formula here) equal 10?

Comment: I'd prefer "*That is*" to "*I.e.*", but that doesn't answer your question of whether "i.e." is a legitimate way to start a sentence.

Comment: @nneonneo Flagging too! Sorry for that!

Comment: Note that "i.e." literally means "that is", but I agree with @DanBron that "that is" is more readable.

Comment: Yeah, it is :) I will edit my question on [math.se] to be "That is"!

Comment: I suspect that we all agree that it shouldn't be "i.e." (lower case) or "I.E.". In my opinion, options 2, 4, and 5 are acceptable, but I would insert a comma before "does" in options 2 and 4.

Comment: Of course you could go into the full Latin and write '*Id est* does (simple formula here) equal 10?' But seriously I always go with your second option and write I.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 'i.e.' exactly where you would put 'that is'.  As you would with that phrase, capitalize only the first letter, and set it off with a comma.

It is common to say "Did he say that?  That is, was it this man who said it?"  So using 'i.e.' that way is also just fine.

Overdone, it can sound clinical or pretentious, perhaps because it is very common in clinical settings, where one asks a short question with a lot of context and then restates the same thing including the context explicitly.  It gives the reader a chance to get oriented to the goal with something simple, and then dig into the details.